# remove strings in list_file from other file(s)

Tags: shell-script, sed

I am attempting to delete any string from a list in the file called `haplotypes` from all `*.txt` files in a directory.  Below is my attempt but something is not working.

`#!/bin/bash
cat haplotypes | while read i; do 
    sed -i -e 's/$i//g' *.txt;
done;`

`haplotypes
100_fullA
100_fullB
105_fullA
105_fullB
112_fullA
112_fullB
121_fullA
121_fullB`

Comment: can you post the sample contents of haplotypes. Also use double quotes. If your haplotypes files has the string line by line ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to transform the pattern file into a `sed` program first, and then run that program on all the files:

```
sed 's/.*/s|&||g/' haplotypes | sed -f - *.txt
```